# Why is my Biquad Filter not disconnecting from my noise properly?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I'm building a white noise generator that can be adjusted to pink noise using a peaking filter. Once I've solved this problem, I intend to add other options as well (brown noise, violet noise, grey noise). The generator works fine when producing white noise, but when I switch from pink to white, I can still hear a faint pink noise in the background. I assume the issue is that I'm not properly disconnecting the filter from the white noise, but I don't understand what I'm doing incorrectly.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <button id="generator-button" onclick="toggleGenerator()">Start</button>
    <select id="noise-type" onchange="changeNoiseType()">
        <option value="white">White Noise</option>
        <option value="pink">Pink Noise</option>
    </select>

    <script>
        let generator, generatorPlaying = false, pinkNoiseEnabled = false;
        const context = new AudioContext();
        const generatorButton = document.getElementById("generator-button"), noiseTypeSelect = document.getElementById("noise-type");

        const toggleGenerator = () => {
            if (!generatorPlaying) {
                generator = playWhite();
                if (pinkNoiseEnabled) generator = playPink(generator);
                generatorPlaying = true;
                generatorButton.innerText = "Stop";
            } else {
                stop(generator);
                generatorPlaying = false;
                generatorButton.innerText = "Start";
            }
        };

        const stop = generator => generator.stop();

        const changeNoiseType = () => {
            const noiseType = noiseTypeSelect.value;
            noiseType === "white" ? removePinkFilter() : addPinkFilter();
        };

        const playWhite = () => {
            const noise = context.createBufferSource();
            noise.buffer = context.createBuffer(1, context.sampleRate, context.sampleRate);
            noise.buffer.getChannelData(0).forEach((_, i) => noise.buffer.getChannelData(0)[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1);
            noise.loop = true;
            noise.connect(context.destination);
            noise.start();
            return noise;
        };

        const playPink = generator => {
            pinkNoiseEnabled = true;
            const filter = context.createBiquadFilter();
            filter.type = "peaking";
            filter.frequency.value = 1000;
            filter.Q.value = 0.5;
            filter.gain.value = -20;
            generator.disconnect();
            generator.connect(filter).connect(context.destination);
            return generator;
        };

        const addPinkFilter = () => pinkNoiseEnabled || (generator = playPink(generator));
        const removePinkFilter = () => {
            pinkNoiseEnabled = false;
            generator.disconnect();
            generator.connect(context.destination);
            return generator;
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me identify what's causing the problem and how to properly remove the pink noise filter (and future filters) from the audio?

*EDIT* I'm not even sure if I am properly creating pink noise. I found reference to many different attempts at creating pink noise and chose to use a BiquadFilter. The concept of my program is to show how white noise can be manipulated to form other types of noise.

Comment: maybe because you are creating a new filter each time a new  onChange event fired

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the pink biquad is still looping through some samples from the noise generator.

I’m not sure what exactly disconnect does, but I found the most reliable way to stop an audio stream is to actively set the gain to to zero.. why not use two gain nodes before the cycle destination instead of unpluging it and replugging the generator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).